# Creating list with multiple conditions in haskell

Tags: haskell

**Define the sequence (bn)n=1,2,… such that bn=3  when n is divisible by 3, and  bn=4(n+1)^2 in other cases.
Define a function that for an argument n creates the list of n initial numbers of the sequence (bn)n=1,2,… .**

so far I have two lists with condition 1 and condition 2:
`` divisible3 n = [x | x <- [1..n], x `mod` 3 == 0] `` 
`` notdivisible3 n = [x*x*4+8*x+4 | x <- [1..n], x `mod` 3 /= 0] ``

 I want it to be one list like:
`list n = [x | x <- [1..n], condition1, condition 2]`

Comment: You should write an `if ... then ... else ...` in the "yield" part of the list comprehension, not a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an `if ... then ... else ...` in the "yield" part of the list comprehension, not a filter. So something like:

```
list n = [ if n `mod` 3 == 0 then … else … | x <- [1..n]]
```

where I leave the `…` parts as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  ```list n = [ if x `mod` 3 == 0 then 3 else x*x*4+8*x+4 | x <- [1..n]]```